# Can't set up neo4jDjango graph database: object has no attribute 'db_type'

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I'm starting a project and I keep getting this error when executing the

```
manage.py sql *ApplicationName*
```

The trace back is as follows:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 304, in handle
    app_output = self.handle_app(app, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sql.py", line 19, in handle_app
    return u'\n'.join(sql_create(app, self.style, connections[options.get('database')])).encode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 31, in sql_create
    output, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, style, known_models)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 44, in sql_create_model
    col_type = f.db_type(connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/utils.py", line 161, in __getattr__
    return getattr(super(AttrRouter, self), name)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'db_type'
```

The code is pretty much a simple example of the tutorial after many attempts to try to solve the problem.

The setings.py are also supposed to be correct, since they are copied from neo4Django tutorial.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'Database.db',  
    }
}

NEO4J_DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'/db/data'
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['neo4django.utils.Neo4djangoIntegrationRouter']
```

Neo4j server is running, and in the sqllite and also in a mysql database things are working, so the problem must be on the neo4j or neo4django side. Also things work when not using neo4Django models in the domain.

The model is as presented:

```
from neo4django.db import models

    class Person(models.NodeModel):
        name = models.StringProperty()
        age = models.IntegerProperty()
        friends = models.Relationship('self',rel_type='friends_with')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `manage.py sql appname` command *(copied from the django documentation)*

> Prints the CREATE TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s).

So If you are going to use `Νeo4j` and not `MySQL` or `SQLite`, there is no need to get the CREATE TABLE SQL statements. Besides that you probably would like to better run the `syncdb` command, but once more you are not using a relational db, but `Neo4j`, so you don't need to run neither.

The only reason you should include a db at the `DATABASES` declaration on your `settings.py` is just because, if you don't, an `ImproperlyConfigured` error will be raised.

So the simple answer is that the error is correct, just don't run any Relational db related django command.

One more tip, don't use the pypi package but the github version https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django (`pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/#egg=neo4django`)